# Adfly while browsing Stack Overflow

Tags: support, advertising, redirection, virus

In the last few days, I've noticed that Stack Overflow gets redirected via AdFly especially when I click on a user. Why is this being done these days? Or am I the only one facing this?

EDIT:

It happened again. Here's a screenshot

[image]

Comment: The SE network will not ever redirect you to an advertising network like that. You probably got a bug on your system or a rogue extension installed.

Comment: This is the second time recently this has been brought up... Maybe there's a correlation?

Comment: Or you’re on evil public wi-fi and Stack Overflow doesn’t use HTTPS yet. \*Cough cough*

Comment: @minitech, they must be getting close, all of SE's imgur (finally) supports TLS, meaning we shall finally have our security (damned TSA...)

Comment: I'm on my home wifi. Havent had this issue before

Comment: @Anil What's your OS?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Can you find a link to the other time?

Comment: @Anil: My suggestion: use Linux. In all sincerity though, I suggest that you backup all your important files and do a very thorough virus scan, possibly from a livecd. *Then* install Linux ;).

Comment: @Linuxios I'm usually on Fedora. But been doing some work with my Windows machine. That's when I ran into this issue

Comment: @Anil: Yay! 1 more down, millions more to go ;).

Comment: @Linuxios unfortunately not. It got status-norepro'd and deleted, as far as I know. Maybe a mod can find it? It was just a screenshot and didn't say "adfly", but it was within a week ago.

Comment: It will keep happening until you remove the malware/virus you got.

Comment: The screenshot makes it obvious it's no SO's fault. Redirect through a remote site is one thing, but a toolbar, advertisement and a ten second delay? No wai.

Comment: @Anil: If you're normally on Fedora, did you try on that? If it doesn't show up in Fedora, it's something in your Windows installation. If it also does show up in Fedora, you might want to check your network for tempering.

Comment: @Anil You should follow [this](http://virus-list-info.blogspot.co.il/2008/09/adfly-adware.html), it also contain steps to remove the adware.

Comment: I took the liberty to report this to adfly, I also provided them with a link here and encouraged them to post an answer here (regarding correct steps taken if such abuse occurs). So it would be nice if this question sticks around.

Comment: @Demonbobby I've been a little busy. I'll look into it and I'll let you know. I work in another city. Came home for the weekend. Dont think I'll be able to check with the same network. But I'll keep my eyes open for anything suspicious

Comment: Just so that you know, I've just got word from adfly, they are contacting that owner of that account about it and will look into it.

Comment: Ian from adfly was also so kind to look it up and [located the removal instructions for that piece of malware/crapware/scareware](http://www.selectionlinks.com/uninstall).

Comment: @Demonbobby, awesome! I did find few malwares when I ran Exterminate It! But no longer at home to see if it did work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As the comments already say: We don't do anything like that. It sounds very much like you have picked up a piece of malware that rewrites the links so the malware author gets a few cents.